# Remove scientific notation representation from a number of type double in C# and WPF

Tags: scientific-notation

I am working with WPF and C# backend. I am having unit conversion package which converts from an inch to mm. All the values in this conversion are double. On UI, once I'm writing "0.000039", it is getting converted into scientific notation as soon as I type '3' of the above value and it is appending '9' to the scientific notation value. To get rid of this I want to remove scientific notation representation of numbers with a double datatype. How to do this? Please help.

Comment: That isn't a thing that just happens. Your program must be intentionally displaying it like that, so change your program to stop it happening. Nothing we can help with if you cannot provide the code that replicates your problem